# Is there any way to find out the Laravel default session die path URL in Laravel project?

Tags: laravel

Actually, I am trying to get the default Laravel session die path URL but I can't find the default Laravel session die path URL. Is there anyone who can help me to find out the default Laravel session die URL path?

Comment: What does "*Laravel session die path URL*" mean?

Comment: @Don't Panic , Laravel session expire path URL

Comment: Do you mean how to log out?  You an use `php artisan route:list` to see all current routes, I guess log out should be something like POST to /logout.

Answer (score 0):

you can hit url for example
[www.abc.com/logout](http://www.abc.com/logout)

and if you want to change redirection or something and you have laravel
basicc setup you can find laravel logout function in LoginController.php File
Something like this`enter code here`

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        activity($user->name)
            ->performedOn($user)
            ->causedBy($user)
            ->log('LoggedOut');
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        return redirect('/');
    }
```